# How to restrict/stop public (internet) access to Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, vnet, azure-http-trigger

I have several Azure Functions (Premium plan) which do some stuff and load the results to the storage blob. The connection to the storage account is restricted by a v-net so no public access to the storage account, however, I check and found that my (HTTP) azure functions can be triggered on the public internet.

How can I restrict this in the azure function, is there a way to do it through configuration?

Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway) the way it's done?
Please help if there're other ways

Answer (score 2):

You can set access restrictions in the portal through the networking blade. Click on Networking, then Configure Access Restrictions, and you can set access rules in there based on various options.

[image: Networking > Access Restrictions]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allowing specific IPS, i would request you to look at access restrictions to an Azure Function.

```
 Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -WebAppName "AppName" `-Name "Multi-source rule" -IpAddress "192.168.1.0/24,192.168.10.0/24,192.168.100.0/24" `
-Priority 100 -Action Allow
```